# How to lock storage accounts in Azure using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-python-sdk, azure-resource-lock

I am using python SDK to lock a particular azure resource. Although I found documentation, I am getting exceptions as a resource not found while I am trying to lock the storage account.

As I am trying to store accounts in a Resource Grp, I'm using the below functionality.

I initiated `Managementlockclient` and `ResourceManagementClient`.

```
lockclient = ManagementLockClient( credential=credential,
                subscription_id=subscriptionid
)

lockclient.management_locks.create_or_update_at_resource_level()
```

Apart from the above, is there any other way to lock all storage accounts in a resource group? I know we have a functionality to lock all resources in an RG using `create_or_update_at_resource_group_level` but I only want to lock storage accounts. So I am using `create_or_update_at_resource_level`.

Can anyone please help?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0RJe.png)

Response :
<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError'> occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> Trying to lock particular storage account resource

You can use **`create_or_update_by_scope`** method to create lock by using scopes of storage account.

You can get the scope of storage account through portal.

*Portal -> storage account -> endpoint -> resource id -> copy-resource-id.*

**Portal:**
[image]

**Code:**
The below code is used to create lock under scope with **`DefaultAzureCredential`** and **`ManagementLockClient`**.

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ManagementLockClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


subscriptionid = "<subscription-id>"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
lockclient = ManagementLockClient( credential=credential,subscription_id=subscriptionid)
lockclient.management_locks.create_or_update_by_scope(scope="/subscriptions/sub-id/resourceGroups/v-venkat-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat326",
      lock_name="demolock",parameters={"level":"CanNotDelete"},content_type = "application/json")
print("Lock created")
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`parent_resource_path` is most likely the resourceId for the resource group?

Something like: `/subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/MyRGName`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.locks.v2016_09_01.aio.operations.managementlocksoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-resource-locks-v2016-09-01-aio-operations-managementlocksoperations-create-or-update-at-resource-level